# Interweave events from using WebLogic and Log4j

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic

I am using WebLogic and Log4j for my Struts application. Since Action class is not thread-safe, I assumed Action classes are cached by WebLogic and re-used for every HTTP request.

In this case, if there are multiple clients accessing the same Action class, I assume the events printed on by Log4j will be output by multiple request.

The log information would not be sequential and very difficult to interpret.

How do I resolve such issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would like to fix some terms usage in your question. Struts is a MVC framework. Weblogic is a Java EE container. The `Action` functionality and life cycle does not depend on container. It is the Struts's functionality only.

You are right, since instance of `Action` is created per request your log will contain a mixture of log messages created by different actions.

The typically used solution is to print thread name into log (log4j supports this configuration), then use `grep` command on unix or `find` on windows to filter only relevant messages.

Here is an example of `layout` configuration that causes log4j to print thread name:

```
           <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
                    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %-23d{ISO8601}{GMT} [%t] %x: %c{1}(%C{1}.%M:%L) - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
```

`[%t]` does the job.

Comment: is there any other more effective methods for multi-threading logging?